# "Type is not cls-compliant" warning in some places but not in others

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-3.5

I have really simple model class in C# with 5 auto properties - 4 `int` and one `string`

```cs
public class MyModel
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public int refId { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int mappingId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

I have in vb.net a class that makes a call and retrieves a list of this model

```vb
Dim models As List(Of MyModel) = DataProvider.GetModels(refId)
```

And this is flies just fine, has been working, no warnings.

But now I am refactoring and building an abstract base class, which receives this list of models in constructor

```vb
Public MustInherit Class MySpecialBase
    Private ReadOnly _models As List(Of MyModel) ' No Warning

    Public Sub New (ByVal models As List(Of MyModel)) 'Warning
        _models = models
    End Sub

    Protected ReadOnly Property Models As List(Of MyModel) ' Warning
        Get
            Return _models
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Even in this abstract class, the warning appears on property and constructor under (Of **MyModel**), but not in private class member.

I don't see how this model is not cls-compliant. Both assemblies (vb and c#) are class libraries. Can someone explain this behavior? Is it VS problem?

Comment: I used your code and created two library project both in .Net Framework 3.5. But I am not getting any kind of error. every thing is perfect. I also tried the same code with different .Net Frameworks but still not getting any error. Let me know which version of VS you are using.

Comment: @NitinJoshi vs 2012. Look my comment on the answer to "Ripple"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly easy to explain, only declarations that are *Public* are checked for CLS compliance.  Your private member cannot violate the rule, other code cannot use it so cannot get into trouble either.

You get the warning because the C# assembly isn't marked as compliant.  You'd have to add this attribute, anywhere you like:

```
   [assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]
```

Do keep in mind that CLS compliance is an outdated concept, it stopped being relevant when .NET 2.0 was released.  Not just because it brought VB.NET up to snuff and deprecated JScript, the notion of *not* considering generics to be non-compliant is a stretch.  Retro-fitting an existing language to support generics is a rather major effort.  Notable is that your class requires a consumer to know how to deal with List(Of T), it isn't going to work with NetCOBOL or Fortran for .NET.  So simplify your life and just remove the attribute from your VB.NET code.

Comment: This is why you make so many points. I had it in front of my eyes and didn't make anything from the fact that private stuff is Ok and public is not... Thank you. I was about to remove that attribute from assembly anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your C# class is not marked as `CLSCompliant`, while VB is.

Check your AssemblyInfo.vb in the VB project.
If it contains `<Assembly: CLSCompliant(True)>`, remove it if you don't need it.
(I've heard it would be automatically added by older version of VS, but I couldn't verify that.)

**EDIT:**
Determining whether a class is CLS-compliant or not depends on its public/protected interface(signature), so using an imcompliant class inside methods or as private/internal members doesn't matter.
"CLS-compliant" means "LOOKS compliant from other assemblies."

Comment: True, vb project comes all the way from 2003 and has `CLSCompliant` in assembly info. True, C# class is not marked as `CLSCompliant` - and doesn't need to - all types in it are compliant. It didn't complain until I used it as argument. In the line code it doesn't complain about it - only on declarations.

Comment: Added explanation about that.